# Issue with cast {reshape}

Tags: r, casting

I have my trouble with casting [`this dataframe`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FklEioHzKC4vEf2XXUH4SmGWhAifE59RD5sf1VngkZw/edit?usp=sharing). I'd like to have the frequencies of species (using `newname`) across `main_habitat` and muncipality (`munc`), with the `main_habitat` and `newname` in rows and all `munc`, with the according frequencies in columns:

```
   main_haitat  newname munc1 munc2 munc3
    A            X      1     1     0
    A            Y      0     1     1
    B            Y       ...
    B            Z       ...
    ...
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast( species, main_habitat + newname ~ munc, fill=0 )
```